# installed php, but there is nothing in /etc/init.d/php

Tags: php, init.d

I read a lot of posts about php problems and ect. They all say to install php, restart apache server and so on..

But the problem is that after I run:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

and even if I check the version:

```
    justas@justas-Lenovo-M490s ~ $ php -v
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

there is nothing about php in my /etc/init.d/ folder. So for example:
if I create something in /var/www/html/ folder, like file info.php with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and then I open localhost/info.php. I get raw data ( ). My php is not firing and not doing anything.

Could someone please give me some info about what is happening?

I've been using Homestead and vagrant setup in the past, but for this project I would love to configure local lamp. Mby homestead, phpadmin is somehow interfering with my vanila setup? :/

Comment: If my Linux is not too rusty, `/etc/init.d` contains start/stop scripts for daemons and system services. PHP is not such thing.

Comment: Just installing PHP is not enough, you of course need to configure your webserver to get files ending in .php actually parsed as PHP.

Comment: https://www.itnota.com/install-apache-mysql-php-on-linux-mint/

most of the guides goes like this, and like I said php files are not working. I am pretty sure that I have configured apatche corectly so it should communicate with php.

if I ssh to my homestead vagrant box. there is /etc/init.d/php7.0-fpm daemon that I can start/restart/etc

Comment: have you also installed (and enabled) the *apache-module* for php?

Comment: I installed php7.0-fpm, and that lets me reach php service comands, but that did not fixed my problem.

@FranzGleichmann I dont clearly understand what did you said. I know that I should install something, but don't know how. Is that module is for php or apatche?

Comment: it is the module for apache that lets it run php. usually named something like *libapache2-mod-php5* and mentioned in every single setup-tutorial for php and apache

Answer (score 0):

I purged apache/php/mysql. Redid everything and it seems that that fixed my problem. I still don't know what caused the issue and why php was not running properly. Because I had configured and installed all necessary models. Mby there were some problems with my old phpadmin configuration that caused some misunderstandings.